# Spring data rest disable CORS on base-path

Tags: cors, spring-data-rest, base-path

I'm developing a REACT app on localhost:3000 and have a spring data rest backend running on localhost:8080. I've found out how to disable CORS policy for specific RestRepositories for example:

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

Now the following URL is accessible: localhost:8080/api/employees

However, I'm trying to execute a GET-request on the base-path url itself: localhost:8080/api. This is still blocked by CORS policy. I want to disable the CORS policy on that URL.

[image]

I've found the following documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.configuring-cors this works for the repositories itself but has no result on the base URL.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

if you created the react app using create-react-app please add the following to the package.json:

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:8080",
```

This will proxy all your requests to the backend server. This is for development only.

Comment: I've put the proxy in 'package.json' however, the same CORS policy blockage comes up. any other idea?